# Translate string literals to their actual values

Tags: c#, string

**NOTE**: I didn't want to make the question too long, so "how" from the question title translates into "is there a method for this in .Net framework".

Just a reminder:

```
\n
```

if the above is printable representation of the string, then its internal version is one character, not two, which code is 0x0a.

However I could write:

```
string s = "\\n"; // three characters in editor
```

which translates to internal representation of 2 characters `\` and `n`. This is not 0x0a character!

But I would like to achieve this. I.e. I have already in string some data, which I know is printable representation of a string. And I would like to convert it to internal representation (something C# compiler does all the time).

```
string printable = "\\n";
string internal_ = convert(printable);
```

`internal_` would hold only one character now, of code 0x0a.

Question: is there **ready to use** (!) function for such conversion?

Comment: You could get the bytes using one of the `Encoding.GetBytes` methods.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, it gives you the bytes of the string, but it does not interpret string. This `convert` could be called multiple times on string, and it would shorten each metacharacter on each call. So in short, it does something different.

Comment: Maybe you need to make your question clearer, since I think you ask for a way to get `0x0a`, not `\\n`.

Comment: So to be clear: you're looking for a method that translates the string `@"\n"` to the character `0x0a`?

Comment: When making localization system for my project I escape/un-escape new line symbol with simple `Replace("\\n", "\xd\xa")` (for escaping opposite). You could make something more convenient, by using same principle.

Comment: @CodeCaster, as an example yes.

Comment: @Sinatr, yes, I know the drill, that's why I asked for something ready to use :-).

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use the [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx) static method:

```
string internal_ = Regex.Unescape(printable);
```

But unfortunately it applicable mainly for Regex control characters.

Test:

```
var chars = internal_.ToCharArray();
```

The `chars` array has 1 element with code `0x0a`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, it is called **UN**escape for a reason. You are mixing it with "escaping" :-).

Comment: @greenoldman: No, your question is unclear.

Comment: Will this work for [_all_ string literal variants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx), like `\uNNNN`?

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not sure about *all*, but for `\uNNNN` it works.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually quite complex, there are many more cases than you describe that need to be accounted for in order to parse string literals. Consider for example `\0x0a`. Fortunately, you are not the first person requesting this. `Regex.Unescape` handles most, but [not all cases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.110).aspx). DeepDiver has [a blog post](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/08/03/ParsingCSharpStrings.aspx) with code that parses C# literal strings - this should do what you request.

Comment: I know it is complex task, that is why I am looking for something to use, not to reinvent. I am still hoping for using Roslyn for this, however this would be heavy weight solution :-)