# Simple way to un-escape escaped unpritable encoded string returned by mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, encoding, escaping

I have checked other similar questions on SO and they either propose to use WebUtility.HtmlDecode() or replace the encoded parts character-by-character or assumes some known regex pattern, etc. They do not answer this specific query.

I have a C# console application, which posts some data to a MVC application. Then the message returned by the service is written to a simple text file. When I write it to the file, the text is like

> "Something didn\u0027t work right while processing this request! \r\nSee detailed logs \u003e d:\\Sandboxes\\UGBNC\\Stage\\Logs\\ArgLog2087129002.log"

What I want is to remove these encoded texts like `\u0027`, `\r\n`, `\\` etc. and format it properly (like, with new line, tab etc.) in my text file. And I don't know what all characters might come, so **I cannot replace them with `string replace` or `regex replace`**, I need a generic solution.

The MVC service returns the data as json with `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`, and my client code is this

```
try
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        //configure request details
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var message = sr.ReadToEnd();
            //process message
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException wex)
{
    using (var stream = wex.Response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var message = reader.ReadToEnd(); //this is the encoded string
        File.AppendAllText("SomeTextFile.txt", message);
    }
}
```

What is the best/simplest way to do this?

**Note:** I don't want to replace them character by character, I want a generic solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Translate string literals to their actual values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589768/translate-string-literals-to-their-actual-values)

Comment: The question marked there actually solved the issue (at least for now), thanks for the direction. The original post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661169/how-can-i-unescape-and-reescape-strings-in-net

Answer (score 3):

From the links in the comments, I got a *working solution*, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661169/how-can-i-unescape-and-reescape-strings-in-net). In short, this worked for now.

```
var unescapedString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(escapedString);
```

Longer version : Little more details for those who might face similar issues.

This is a typical sample of the strings that I was trying to make sane (readable & printable)

> "Something didn\u0027t work right while processing this request! \r\nSee detailed logs \u003e d:\Sandboxes\UGBNC\Stage\Logs\ArgLog2087129002.log"

(1) Though the string came from a web response, this was not HTML, rather a JSON. So, the HTML decode methods like new `WebUtility.HtmlDecode(str)` or older System.Web `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(str)` did not work.

(2) Characters like `\u0027` are unicode characters (this ones for apostrophe '), but trying with `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` yielded no good result. (Maybe I missed the trick!)

(3) Basically what I needed was to convert characters like `\u0027`, `\r\n`, `\\` to their printable format. For that the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape()` method worked fine on my strings. This method converts all the escaped characters in the string to their unescaped form.

**Note:** Anyone using this method, please refer the [msdn doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.110).aspx) first. This method has some limitations, it's not perfect and might give wrong result in some scenarios.

Check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/08bb20a2-82b9-4f2f-9f1a-994961fbecc3/get-string-with-escape-character?forum=netfxbcl) & [this](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/08/03/ParsingCSharpStrings.aspx) for better solutions.